# WebSocket connection slows down webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, websocket

I have an app that uses axios, socket and chagstreams that keeps track of data in mongodb.
When the user clicks the like or dislike button it send a axios.post request and updates the database. Then changestream then picks up on the change and fires a socket.emit() to send the new data to the front. In the front the updated data is stored in a state hook.

Clientside.js

```
function Home() {
  var { username } = useParams();
  const { state } = useLocation();  
  if (state !== null) {
    var { validation } = state;
  }
  const [SearchedData, setSearchedData] = useState();
  const [MainData, setMainData] = useState();
  const socket = io("ws://localhost:5000");

  React.useEffect(() => {
      socket.emit("content");
      socket.on("get-data", (data) => {
        setMainData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  socket.on("Updated", (data) => {
    if (JSON.stringify(MainData) !== JSON.stringify(data)) 
      setMainData(data);
  });
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar
        CurrentUser={username}
        SearchedData={setSearchedData}
        MainData = {MainData}
        socket={socket}
        validation={validation}
      />
      {MainData !== undefined ? (
        <Content
          CurrentUser={username}
          SearchedData={SearchedData}
          MainData={MainData}
          validation={validation}
        ></Content>
      ) : (
        <Loading></Loading>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

route.js

```
router.post("/:username/like", (req,res) => {
  const {username, id} = req.body
      Comments.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {score: username}}, {upsert: true}, (err, d) => {
        if(err){
            res.sendStatus(400)
        }
        else{
          res.sendStatus(200)
          console.log(d['_id'] + " Liked")
        }
      })
})

router.post("/:username/dislike", (req,res) => {
  const {username, id} = req.body

      Comments.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$pull: {score: username}}, (err, d) => {
        if(err){
          res.sendStatus(400)
        }
        else{
          res.sendStatus(200)
          console.log(d['_id'] + " DisLiked")
        }
      })
})
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const socket = require("socket.io");
const server = app.listen(process.env.Port, () => {
  console.log("Socket listening " + process.env.Port);
});
const io = socket(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credential: true,
  },
});
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MongoDB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database Connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
io.on("connection", (socket) => {

  const changeStream = Comments.watch();
  changeStream
  .on("change", (next) => {
    Comments.find({}, (err, save) => {
      socket.emit("Updated", save.reverse());
    });
  })
  .on("error", err => {
    console.log(err)
  })

  socket.on("content", (username) => {
    var recievedData;
    Comments.find({}, function (err, data) {
      if (!err) {
        recievedData = data;
        socket.emit("get-data", recievedData.reverse());
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on("user-data", (username) => {
    Users.find({ username: username }, (err, save) => {
      if (!err) socket.emit("recieve-user-data", save);
    });
  });

})
```

Content.js

```
function Content(props) {
  const [MainDisplay, setMainDisplay] = useState();
  const [Recusers, setRecusers] = useState()
  const [DeleteModal, setDeleteModal] = useState({delete: false, id: ""})
  const [DeetsIndex, setDeetsIndex] = useState(-1)
  const [EditModal, setEditModal] = useState({edit: false, id: ""})

  const onLike = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const data = {
      username: props.CurrentUser,
      id: id,
    };

    axios
      .post(process.env.REACT_APP_baseServerurl + "/user/:username/like", data)
  };

  const onDislike = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();  
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const data = {
      username: props.CurrentUser,
      id: id,
    };
      axios
        .post(process.env.REACT_APP_baseServerurl + "/user/:username/dislike", data)
  };

  const DeetsList = (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset
    if(DeetsIndex == id)
      setDeetsIndex(-1)
    else{
      setDeetsIndex(id)
    }
  }
  
  const DeleteConfirmation = (id) => {
    setDeleteModal(DeleteModal => ({ 
      delete: true, id: id
    }))
    setDeetsIndex(-1)
  }

  const Edit = (id) => {
    setEditModal(EditModal => ({
      edit: true, id: id
    }))
    setDeetsIndex(-1)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.SearchedData !== undefined && props.setSearchedData !== "") {
      if(props.SearchedData["users"].length > 0){
        setRecusers(props.SearchedData["users"])
      }
      setMainDisplay(props.SearchedData['comments']);
    } 
    else if(JSON.stringify(MainDisplay) !== JSON.stringify(props.MainData)) {
      setMainDisplay(props.MainData);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="Comment-container">
      {(Recusers === undefined || props.SearchedData === undefined || Recusers.length === 0 )? <></> : <DisplayUsers users={Recusers}></DisplayUsers>}
      {(DeleteModal.delete)? <Delete DeleteModal={[DeleteModal,setDeleteModal]} ></Delete> : <></>}
      {(EditModal.edit)? <EditContent EditModal={[EditModal, setEditModal]} ></EditContent> : <></>}
      {MainDisplay !== undefined ? (
        MainDisplay.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="Comments" id={data["_id"]}>
              <div className="Likes">
                <div className="like">
                  <svg
                    viewBox="0 0 32 32"
                    data-id={data["_id"]}
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    onClick={onLike}
                  >
                    <path
                      data-id={data["_id"]}
                      d="M28,14H18V4c0-1.104-0.896-2-2-2s-2,0.896-2,2v10H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h10v10c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2  s2-0.896,2-2V18h10c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <p id="score">{data["score"].length}</p>
                <div className="dislike">
                  <svg
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    data-id={data["_id"]}
                    className="dislike"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    onClick={onDislike}
                  >
                    <path
                      data-id={data["_id"]}
                      d="M18,11H6c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h12c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S19.104,11,18,11z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="Comment-header">
                <div className="Comment-info">
                  <div className="inner-header">
                    <div>
                      <img alt="profile-pic" src={data["avatar"]}></img>
                    </div>
                    <p className="Username">{data["username"]}</p>
                  </div>
                  <p>{data["createdAt"]}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                  <p>{data["content"]}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="deets">
                <img
                  className="deet-img"
                  data-id={index}
                  src={require("./images/deets.png")}
                  width="40px"
                  onClick={DeetsList}
                ></img>
                {
                  (DeetsIndex == index)? 
                  <ul className="deet-list" data-index={index}>
                    {(props.validation && props.CurrentUser === data["username"])? 
                      <>
                        <li onClick={() => {DeleteConfirmation(data["_id"])}}>Delete</li>
                        <li onClick={() => {Edit(data["_id"])}}>Edit</li>
                      </>
                    :
                    <></>
                  }
                  <li onClick={() => {DeleteConfirmation(data["_id"])}}>Share</li>
                  </ul>
                      :
                  <></>
                }
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <Loading></Loading>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Problem:**

After a few requests or minutes (idle time) the console displays connection errors in loop and the web browser slows down.

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=-Y4oqgeERHo7ernXABEn.\
```

1. Tried to run the app in Chrome but it has the same slowing down problem without any errors.

In both the browsers if i check the network tab it shows pending requests.

2. Tried to insert some string from the front end. It works fine the first few times then it begins to slow down. So i guess the problem is some where in the routes part where it sends the request to store the data in the DB cause when i enter the data and check my collection on the mongodb website/ Compass there is no data of such it appears only when the request has been successfully completed. Switching it entirely to sockets also made no difference

I don't think the error is the main problem. It just that the browser slows down..

**Update:**

*I think i solved the problem. It was initially triggering socket.on("Updated") multiple times and with each request it kept on increasing. So right now the performance seems normal. ***I just replaced socket.on("Updated") with socket.once("Updated")***..*

Comment: Have you tried printing in your various functions? Are you seeing an unusual amount of function invocations?

Comment: Yea.. In one of the function, Everytime there are changes in the db it updates the state in the useEffect hook and after every change the number of time it executes increases..

Comment: i have fixed the multiple invocation problem but that didn't solve the slow problem.

Comment: Can you share how have you implemented `Comments` class? Need to ensure that you are using a `single db connection` or at least closing connection properly after usage (if using multiple connections)

Comment: i guess u mean content class.. Anyways i updated it

Comment: thanks for sharing! from your code style, it is possible that there is a circular call that overload your service and causes this issue. From your current code - I can't find any circular calls (e.g. - client emit to server, server postback to client, client emit to server again and so forth) but is is possible that one of your user's APIs (such as `user-data`) is making this issue. My advice: create a simple screen that only tests your connection to socket server. Then, add more components until things are getting broken again. That should help you to find circular calls

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the state being updated multiple times. Once the DB has been updated. It triggers socket.emit("Updated") and then the received data is stored in the state (In the Home component).